# How can I derive the equations of motion with the least action principle from the action of $p$-Form Electrodynamics?

Tags: electromagnetism, lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle, action, variational-calculus

[image: Action in p-Form Electrodynamics]

I know this is the correct formula for the action for a arbitrary $p$. I know how to obtain the equations of motion for $p=1$, but I struggle to find a way to do this with an arbitrary $p$. I also know what the correct equations of motion are:

[[image: Equations of motion]]
I got the first one, but struggle to get the second one. How can I interpret that physically? What does this equation Tell me and how can I obtain them?